# Remove Portion of Email and Remove Duplicates

Tags: php, file

I have a text file with various names, tags and emails in it. I have managed to extract the data so that only the emails show in a list. Now I need to remove the string data up to the @ symbol. In other words only the domain part (like domain.com) should be left.

Then after that I need to remove the duplicate domains. How would I do this last bit of the exercise? This is the php code I have so far:

```
<?php

$string = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
if($result) {
    foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) {
        echo $email . "<br />";
    } 
}
```

Edit:
Ok, so I added the following code to my if statement:

```
if($result) {
    foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) {
        $domain = strstr($email, '@', false);
        $domain1 = str_replace('@', '', $domain);
        echo $domain1 . '<br />';
    } 
}
```

This gives me the domain part of the email. Now I need to 
1. remove all duplicates and
2. sort alphabetically by domain name

It does not seem as if I can use the array_unique() function as this is not an array. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `explode("@", $email)`? This should do what you want.

Comment: Side note: Is there a particular reason as to why you're not using a database for this? What you're using now requires a lot of work, maintenance-wise. Plus, I hope you've made sure to not have anyone be able to access/guess its location.

Comment: How would I use explode("@", $email) in this context? - @TobiasF.

Comment: Take a look at the corresponding page in the [manual](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), it should be pretty much self-explaining.

Comment: The result of `explode` is an array.  `resust[0]` will contain the user part, `result[1]` will contain the domain part, since you split on "@".

Answer (score 1):

You can do it three ways....

Regular Expression

```
$email  = 'someone@domain.com';
preg_match("/\@(.*)/", $email, $domain);
echo $domain[1];
```

Using explode

```
$email  = 'someone@domain.com';
$domain = explode ("@", $email);
echo $domain[1];
```

Using substr

```
$email  = 'someone@domain.com';
$domain = substr($email, strpos($email, "@") + 1);
echo $domain;
```

All of above gives same output.

```
domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, this was the code that did the trick

```
<?php

$string = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
$domains = [];
if($result) {
    foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) {
    $domain = strstr($email, '@', false);
    $domain1 = str_replace('@', '', $domain);
    $domains[$domain1] = $domain1;
} 
asort($domains);
foreach($domains as $domain) {
    echo $domain . '<br />';
}
}
```